# How can I split pandas dataframe into column of tuple, quickly?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pd.Series element of strings, separated by `'_'`, with only two elements in it.

for instance,

```
s = pd.Series([a_1, a_2, a_3, b_1])
```

the command `s.str.split("_")` will return a series of lists

```
0   ['a', '1']
1   ['a', '2']
2   ['a', '3']
3   ['b', '1']
```

the command `s.str.partition("_", expand=False)` will return a series of tuples, where `_` will be the second element in the tuple

```
0   ('a', '_', '1')
1   ('a', '_', '2')
2   ('a', '_', '3')
3   ('b', '_', '1')
```

Is there a clean (and fast) way to create a series of tuples without `_` in it:

```
0   ('a', '1')
1   ('a', '2')
2   ('a', '3')
3   ('b', '1')
```

I can always do: `s.str.split("_").apply(tuple)`, but apply is always slower than built-in functions (like `str.split`...)

Comment: Create a dataframe of 2 columns seems to be easier and faster

Comment: I need it to be a one-column of tuple...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea is use list comprehension:

```
s = pd.Series('a_1, a_2, a_3, b_1'.split(', '))
#4k rows
s = pd.concat([s] * 1000, ignore_index=True)

In [195]: %timeit s.str.split("_").apply(tuple)
2.49 ms ± 41.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [196]: %timeit [tuple(x.split('_')) for x in s]
1.46 ms ± 79.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [197]: %timeit pd.Index(s).str.split("_", expand=True).tolist()
4.31 ms ± 14.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

---

```
s = pd.Series('a_1, a_2, a_3, b_1'.split(', '))
#400k rows
s = pd.concat([s] * 100000, ignore_index=True)

In [199]: %timeit s.str.split("_").apply(tuple)
252 ms ± 4.63 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [200]: %timeit [tuple(x.split('_')) for x in s]
180 ms ± 370 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [201]: %timeit pd.Index(s).str.split("_", expand=True).tolist()
379 ms ± 1.73 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```